# Is there a way to fade influence in editor mode?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to bend vertices into a loose spiral, but the "bend" tool is too loose and it doesn't let me constrain it to axis.

So, what I thought is I can rotate the vertices, but with a type of fuzzy or faded gradient influence. Is there a way to do this in editor mode for a mesh?

Comment: You are probably looking for "Proportional editing

Comment: Yup, thank you.